# Is there a calculator or set of formulas for estimating aerobraking on Mars?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, mathematics, aerodynamics, aerobraking

I am looking for a calculator or formulas that can be used to calculate the aerobraking on Mars mission.

I have found some data on previous Mars flights where aerobraking was used and all my current formulas applied fail to produce proper results. I do not need very accurate algorithm, just the estimations (something where for given mass, front area (flat), orbit(apo, peri) I get delta-v, heat generated in pass, pressure (N/m&2) in lowest point and new orbit).

Comment: Do you need the equations for aerobreaking?  Or the equations that model the Martian atmosphere?  If you are a student, [STK](http://www.agi.com/products/engineering-tools) from AGI can be obtained for free and has a martian atmosphere model.